# Strange behaviour with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am building a project using react hooks. My `useEffect` function looks as follows...

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async function() {
    const queryParams = await qs.parse(props.location.search, { ignoreQueryPrefix: true }).code;
    if (queryParams != undefined) {
      setCode(queryParams);
      postLogin();
    }
  })();
});
```

The `postLogin` function is just a `GET` request to a server using the query parameters defined above. It look as so...

```
const postLogin = async () => {
  await axios.get("http://XXX.XXX.X.XX:52805/user/auth", {
    params: {
      auth_code: code
    }
  }).then(result => {
    setAuthTokens(result.data.credentials.access_token);
    setLoggedIn(true);
  }).catch(e => {
    setIsError(true);
  });
}
```

What happens is that the request will get called multiple times when I only want it to get called once.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above, out of the 5 requests, one of them is successful, the others fail, and I'm not sure what is causing it. Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to add an empty array ( `[]` ) as the second parameter to your hook. It stops the hook from running multiple times.

The array is supposed to contain variables ( normally part of the component's state ) that the hook should watch and rerun if they change.
The variables should be vital for whatever the hook does.

Let's say your hook is supposed to display number of subscribers to a youtube channel in a certain **category** - let's say the categories are A, B and C (hypothetically) and the user can switch between which category to view may be using a dropdown; then the array would contain the **category** variable such that whenever it changes, the hook runs to fetch the number of subscribers in that category. Having the array empty is a way of telling **React** that you have no dependencies and you are ok with what the hook does the first time it runs.

**React** compares the values in that array for changes on each render and if they don't change, the hook is skipped. If you have it empty, then no value will ever change which means the hook will run once and then be skipped on subsequent rerenders.

Comment: You might explain *why*, i.e. what the array parameter is for.

Comment: An empty parameter fixed the issue. Since my `useEffect` function is dependent on the `queryParams` variable, it seems I will have to add that in the second parameter.

Comment: @Bolboa queryParams is only first defined inside the scope of that effect callback, so it's not a dependency. However, if setCode is a setter of a state variable, you'll likely need to include `code` (or whatever you've called the state variable).

Answer (score 1):

Your `useEffect` hook runs on each render. Since you call `setIsError` or `setLoggedIn` after the request finishes, this will trigger another render, and another render, etc. Honestly I'm surprised there isn't an infinite loop. To fix this, try making it only attempt to log in when it hasn't attempted before (hasn't had an error and isn't logged in currently.) Like this:

```
useEffect(async () => {
  if (isLoggedIn || isError) return; // Don't try again if a request has already succeeded or failed.
  // Optionally use "isLoggedIn || isError || isLoading" to prevent multiple concurrent requests,
  // which may cause further re-rendering.
  const queryParams = await qs.parse(props.location.search, { ignoreQueryPrefix: true }).code;
  if (queryParams != undefined) {
    setCode(queryParams);
    postLogin();
  }
});
```

If you are sure that you only ever want it to run once (on the first render) give it an empty dependency array so it will never run again.

Comment: ```useEffect``` hook can't have an async function as callback. It must my sync and declare the async func as OP is doing.